# MySQL Update multiple rows for all users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm scratching my head on this one.

I have to update the score field for all of the users in my database table who have multiple entries in that database table...but it only updates the score field if one of the arguments/constraints is met below.

For example there are two rows (for each user) in the table for 2 Goalkeepers but only one of them will be updated. The following works but only when there is one user...so only 2 rows in database table for 2 goalkeepers.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE Points 
SET Points.Score=(SELECT Week_22.TP FROM Week_22 WHERE    
Week_22.Player=Points.Player) 
WHERE Position='Goalkeeper' AND Active='yes' AND Played='yes'
OR Position='Goalkeeper' AND Active='no' AND Played='yes'
OR Position='Goalkeeper' AND Active='no' AND Played='no'
LIMIT 1
");
```

I thought GROUP BY might work but no luck. So I can't think how to expand the above to work for every field and user in the table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `LIMIT 1`...

Comment: No luck...I changed the "Active" & "Played" fields for all the rows in the table to "yes" and "yes".... and those with a Goalkeeper as the position were updated (the score field)...so that was all of them...when only one row (goalkeeper) per user should be updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parenthesis in the WHERE clause to separate your 3 main 'OR' logic statements

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE Points 
SET Points.Score=(SELECT Week_22.TP FROM Week_22 WHERE    
Week_22.Player=Points.Player) 
WHERE (Position='Goalkeeper' AND Active='yes' AND Played='yes')
OR (Position='Goalkeeper' AND Active='no' AND Played='yes')
OR (Position='Goalkeeper' AND Active='no' AND Played='no')
");
```